# Rails 5 - After registration, assign role and remove default role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rolify

I'm using Rails 5.2.3 with Devise and Rolify. On registration I am assigning a default role to all users, called `pending`. This works great but in certain situations I want to pass a parameter to the registration controller or user model to allow one of the following situations (doesn't matter which one, I'm fine with either):

- The model overrides the default role and creates the new role instead
- The registration happens as it usually would and afterwards a new role is added (`client`) and the default role (`pending`) is removed.

This is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  has_one_attached :avatar
  has_many :bookings, :class_name => 'Booking', :foreign_key => :user_id
  has_many :clients, :class_name => 'Booking', :foreign_key => :client_id
  before_create :set_username
  after_create :assign_default_role, :send_registration_mail
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  def assign_default_role
    # Assign the default user role after the user is created.
    add_role(:pending) if self.roles.blank?
  end

  def set_username
    # Generate a unique username before creating the user.
    self.username = "#{self.email[/^[^@]+/]}-#{SecureRandom.hex(1)}"
  end

  def send_registration_mail
    # Use a delayed job to send the registration email.
    SendRegistrationEmailJob.set(wait: 20.seconds).perform_later(self)
  end
end
```

Here's my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, :store_location, if: :devise_controller?

  def record_activity(note)
    @activity = Activity_Log.new
    @activity.user = current_user
    @activity.note = note
    @activity.browser = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    @activity.ip_address = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
    @activity.controller = controller_name 
    @activity.action = action_name 
    @activity.params = params.inspect
    @activity.save
  end

  # Store login redirect location if it exists
  def store_location
    session[:passthru] = params[:passthru] if params[:passthru]
  end

  # Redirect to the desired location or default
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_name)
    if session[:passthru]
      session.delete(:passthru)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_name)
    if session[:passthru]
      if params[:role] = 'client'
        user.add_role (:client)
        pending_role = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT id from roles where name = pending LIMIT 1").first
        sqlRemovePendingRole = "DELETE FROM users_roles WHERE user_id = #{ current_user.id } AND role_id = #{ pending_role[0] };"
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sqlRemovePendingRole)
      end
      session.delete(:passthru)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    # Permit the `mobile_number` parameter along with the other
    # Sign up parameters.
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:mobile_number])
    # Permit the `passthru` parameter along with the other
    # Sign in parameters.
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:passthru, :role])
  end
end
```

This is my view where I'm trying to do the registration when passing the role:

```
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      Put booking form here

    <% else %>
      Please <%= link_to "log in", new_user_session_path(:passthru => user_booking_path(@user.username)) %> to book <%= @user.firstname %> <%= @user.surname%>.<br />
      Don't have an account yet? <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path(:passthru => user_booking_path(@user.username), :role => "client") %>
    <% end %>
```

I tried passing variables from the controller to the model (I know I shouldn't) to try to override the default role but that didn't work so I tried the code above to change the role after registration (`after_sign_up_path_for` action). Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can modify it in registration controller itself in create action   you can add your lines

Comment: Would it be possible at all to override the registration controller's create action from the application controller or would I need to create my own registration controller?

Comment: as you are using the devise you will get the registration controller,,,, `$ rails generate devise:controllers [scope]` this will generate the controllers for you. dont forget to create new routes like `devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }` and you will get the controller codes here:https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise just copy and paste the content. this might be useful for future instead keep on overwriting the controller actions you could modify this like you want.

Comment: What's not working @DerekC? The line `user.add_role (:client)` in your controller?

Comment: @SRack, everything in the ```if params[:role] = 'client'``` block doesn't run. I've also tried moving that code above the ```if session[:passthru]``` block but nothing changes. The user is still assigned the ```pending``` role on registration and the ```user.add_role (:client)``` doesn't happen, nor does the default (```pending```) role removal happen.

Comment: I solved it by storing the role parameter in a session and running it in the ```after_sign_in_path_for``` action instead of the ```after_sign_up_path_for``` action.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Here's the solution for anyone who ever has the same problem.

I ended up storing the role parameter in a session, then running the `client` role creation and `pending` role removal code in the `after_sign_in_path_for` action instead of `after_sign_up_path_for` action. Also changed the way I read the role ids and current user so the code doesn't give me any errors.

My application controller looks like this now.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, :store_location, if: :devise_controller?

  def record_activity(note)
    @activity = Activity_Log.new
    @activity.user = current_user
    @activity.note = note
    @activity.browser = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    @activity.ip_address = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
    @activity.controller = controller_name 
    @activity.action = action_name 
    @activity.params = params.inspect
    @activity.save
  end

  # Store login redirect location if it exists
  def store_location
    session[:passthru] = params[:passthru] if params[:passthru]
    session[:role] = params[:role] if params[:role]
  end

  # Redirect to the desired location or default
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if session[:role]
      current_user.add_role (:client)
      pending_role = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT id from roles where name = 'pending' LIMIT 1").first
      sqlRemovePendingRole = "DELETE FROM users_roles WHERE user_id = #{ current_user.id } AND role_id = #{ pending_role['id'] };"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sqlRemovePendingRole)
      session.delete(:role)
    end

    if session[:passthru]
      session.delete(:passthru)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if session[:passthru]
      session.delete(:passthru)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    # Permit the `mobile_number` parameter along with the other
    # Sign up parameters.
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:mobile_number])
    # Permit the `passthru` parameter along with the other
    # Sign in parameters.
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:passthru, :role])
  end
end
```